# Logging JPA SQL with Weblogic 10.3

Tags: java, logging, oracle10g, weblogic, openjpa

By looking into the Open JPA website i've found that i can log the generated SQL by using the following:

```
<property name="openjpa.Log" value="DefaultLevel=WARN, Runtime=INFO, Tool=INFO"/>
```

If i try to add the above property to my persistence.xml i get the following warning from weblogic:

```
<Warning> <J2EE> <BEA-160202> <You have specified a ope
njpa.Log setting in your configuration for persistence unit services.ear#services-ejb.jar#exp#exp. This setting will be ignored, and all log messages
will be sent to the WebLogic logging subsystem. Trace-level logging is controlle
d by the various JPA-specific debug settings in config.xml, or via the WebLogic
console.>
```

Anyone know what is the option in the console or how i can edit my config.xml to output the SQL?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the [OTN Discussion forum](http://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=762974&tstart=0) here are the steps :

> - Log into the weblogic console
> - Lock and Edit the session
> - Click Environment | Servers
> - Select the server you wish to monitor/debug
> - Click the Debug tab
> - expand the weblogic tree and select the JPA node
> - Click the enable button
> - Activate the changes.

It might depend on the version of WLS you have. I understand that there were some issues if you've downloaded a [newer version of OpenJPA](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/OPENJPA-384) and are using it with WLS.

WebLogic issues aside, the configuration string you posted looks a bit off. Did you intend to use something like this  (added in SQL=TRACE):

```
<property name="openjpa.Log" 
                value="DefaultLevel=WARN, Runtime=INFO, Tool=INFO, SQL=TRACE"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

For Weblogic 10.3.3, there's some more steps:

- Log into the weblogic console
- Lock and Edit the session
- Click Environment | Servers
- Select the server you wish to monitor/debug
- Click the Debug tab, expand the weblogic tree and select the JPA node
- Click the enable button
- Activate the changes at the bottom of the page
- Now click the Logging Tab
- At the bottom of the page, click Advanced
- Under **Message destination(s)** panel, change **Severity Level** from **Standard Out** to *Debug*
- Save your changes and restart server